# how to host nestjs application in windows iis server

Tags: socket.io, nestjs, mediasoup

i want to host nestjs application in windows iis server. i generated dist file using npm build. these are the files generated
[files after generating dist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsxeY.png)

[added my application in iis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enHP0.png)

**web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="main.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>

<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="nodejs">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/main.js" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <hiddenSegments>
      <add segment="node_modules" />
      <add segment="iisnode" />
    </hiddenSegments>
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

someone please help with the hosting

Answer (score 0):

To host yout NestJs application you will need to use IIS like a proxy to your dist code.

Run the aplication with `npm install` and `npm start` (or the script to start yout back end).

After that you will have your backend running locally with an assigned port. So configure your IIS to work like a reverse proxxy for you application, like on this post: https://tecadmin.net/set-up-reverse-proxy-using-iis/